# param is missing or the value is empty: breads

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the ruby on rails docs as a guide, but I'm getting stuck on my first form. Instead of the "articles" resource, I'm using a resource called "breads". However, when I go to submit my form at breads/new, I get the error:

ActionController::ParameterMissing in BreadsController#create 
param is missing or the value is empty: bread

**app/views/breads/new.html.erb:**

```
<h1>New Breads!</h1>
<%= form_for :bread, url: breads_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :type %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :type %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

**app/controllers/breads_controller.rb:**

```
class BreadsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @bread = Bread.new(bread_params)

    @bread.save
    redirect_to @bread
  end

  private
    def bread_params
      params.require(:bread).permit(:type)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your code, see below

In the `new` action initialize an object of `Bread` class and use that in `new.html.erb`, by `convention over configuration` rails will automatically assign url of create action to the form

**view**

```
<h1>New Breads!</h1>
<%= form_for @bread do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :type %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :type %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

**controller**

```
class BreadsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @bread = Bread.new
  end

  def create
    @bread = Bread.new(bread_params)

    @bread.save
    redirect_to @bread
  end

  private
    def bread_params
      params.require(:bread).permit(:type)
    end
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! That seems to work, but could you explain why I needed to get rid of the "url: breads_path" bit in the form?

Comment: Because `breads_path` points to the index action of Breads controller, also its better to use object if available

Comment: It looks like I created an error by using "type" as a field.